# Not able to clear widgets in kivymd

Tags: kivy, kivymd

The images are getting added to the previous already present images. So, every time I click the button the number of images are multiplied.

```
    def viewmed(self):
        image_data = [
            {"path": "img1.jpeg", "subtitle": "Image 1"},
            {"path": "img2.jpeg", "subtitle": "Image 2"},
            {"path": "img3.jpeg", "subtitle": "Image 3 Subtitle"}
        ]

        my_screen = self.root.get_screen("viewmed")
 
        # Get a list of all the swiperitems in the layout.
        swiperitems = my_screen.ids.swiperitems.children

        # Delete all of the swiperitems from the layout.
        for swiperitem in swiperitems:
            my_screen.ids.swiperitems.remove_widget(swiperitem)

        # Create new swiperitems for the new images.
        new_swiperitems = []
        for data in image_data:
            new_swiperitems.append(
                MDSwiperItem(
                    MDCard(
                        ClickableImage(
                            source=data["path"],
                            size_hint=(1, 0.8),
                            radius=(10, 10, 0, 0),
                            on_release=lambda x, path=data["path"]: self.viewImage(path, data["subtitle"]),
                        ),
                    MDLabel(
                            text=data["subtitle"],
                            halign="center",
                        ),
                        orientation='vertical',
                        size_hint=(0.8, 0.8),
                    )
                )
            )

        # Add the new swiperitems to the layout.
        for swiperitem in new_swiperitems:
            my_screen.ids.swiperitems.add_widget(swiperitem)

        self.root.current = "viewmed"

    def viewImage(self, path, subtitle):
        image = KivyImage(source=path, size_hint=(1, 1), allow_stretch=True, keep_ratio=True)
        popup = Popup(title=subtitle, content=image, size_hint=(1, .8))
        popup.open()`
```

`

This is the function I have written, it is duplicating the images on each button click.

Comment: Try using `my_screen.ids.swiperitems.clear_widgets()` instead of a loop.

Comment: still not working